# Add PSVariable object to array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add a parameter name and value to an array. See example code below:

```
function Test-Params {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        $Param1,
        $Param2,
        $Param3
    )

    $command = $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName
    $parameterList = (Get-Command -Name $command).Parameters

    # Store parameter values
    foreach ($parameter in $parameterList) {
        $parameters = Get-Variable -Name $parameter.Values.Name -EA SilentlyContinue
    }
    $parameters
}
```

Running the function with: `Test-Params -Param1 "Apple" -Param2 "Orange" -Param3 "Pear"`

Shows the output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                        
Param1                         Apple                                                                                                                                                                        
Param2                         Orange                                                                                                                                                                       
Param3                         Pear
```

All OK so far. Now I want to add a new variable to the array. I have tried:

```
New-Variable -Name "Param4" -Value "Banana"
$parameters += $param4
```

But this does not insert the key value pair in the correct way. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `$parameters += $param4` -> `$parameters += Get-Variable param4`. Although I suspect you don't actually need any of this, take a look at `$PSBoundParameters` instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the *value* of the variable, not the *variable object*, like what `Get-Variable` returns.

```
New-Variable -Name "Param4" -Value "Banana"
Write-Host $param4
Write-Host $param4.Name # blank because the property does not exist
$parameters += Get-Variable -Name "Param4" # is what you want
```